# How to record audio while recognising speech using Google Cloud Speech API in Java

Tags: java

I have implemented speech recognition using Google Cloud Speech API and getting the desired output. But my requirement was to record audio at the same time so to record audio i used this code from net with java sound api.

```
public class JavaSoundRecorder {
// record duration, in milliseconds
static final long RECORD_TIME = 60000;  // 1 minute

// path of the wav file
File wavFile = new File("E:/Test/RecordAudio.wav");

// format of audio file
AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

// the line from which audio data is captured
TargetDataLine line;

/**
 * Defines an audio format
 */
AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 16000;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
    int channels = 2;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = true;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                                         channels, signed, bigEndian);
    return format;
}

/**
 * Captures the sound and record into a WAV file
 */
void start() {
    try {
        AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        // checks if system supports the data line
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();   // start capturing

        System.out.println("Start capturing...");

        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

        System.out.println("Start recording...");

        // start recording
        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
 */
void finish() {
    line.stop();
    line.close();
    System.out.println("Finished");
}

/**
 * Entry to run the program
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JavaSoundRecorder recorder = new JavaSoundRecorder();

    // creates a new thread that waits for a specified
    // of time before stopping
    Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(RECORD_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder.finish();
        }
    });

    stopper.start();

    // start recording
    recorder.start();
}
```

}

when i use this code alodeit is recording the audio but when start the speech recognition and audio recording at the same time i'm getting this error

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_UNSIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame,  not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
at Try_Google_Speech_Recognition_Simple.JavaSoundRecorder.start(JavaSoundRecorder.java:50)
at Try_Google_Speech_Recognition_Simple.JavaSoundRecorder.main(JavaSoundRecorder.java:100)
at Try_Google_Speech_Recognition_Simple.TryGoogleSpeechRecognitionSimple$3.actionPerformed(TryGoogleSpeechRecognitionSimple.java:156)
```

When i googled it i found that this exception comes when i start two data line t the same time. But my requirement was to start at the same time. So please do say how to implement it in java . I found same question in Android . But as a newbie i'm not able to figure it out.

Code I'm using for speech recognition

```
    duplex.addResponseListener(new GSpeechResponseListener() {
        String old_text = "";

        public void onResponse(GoogleResponse gr) {
            String output = "";
            output = gr.getResponse();
            if (gr.getResponse() == null) {
                this.old_text = response.getText();
                if (this.old_text.contains("(")) {
                    this.old_text = this.old_text.substring(0, this.old_text.indexOf('('));
                }
                System.out.println("Paragraph Line Added");
                this.old_text = ( response.getText() + "\n" );
                this.old_text = this.old_text.replace(")", "").replace("( ", "");
                response.setText(this.old_text);
                return;
            }
            if (output.contains("(")) {
                output = output.substring(0, output.indexOf('('));
            }
            if (!gr.getOtherPossibleResponses().isEmpty()) {
                output = output + " (" + (String) gr.getOtherPossibleResponses().get(0) + ")";
            }
            //System.out.println(output);
            response.setText("");
            response.append(this.old_text);
            response.append(output);
         REcognise=output;
            System.out.println(REcognise);
            recordBar.setToolTipText(REcognise);
                                    //response.append(REcognise);
            //response.setText(REcognise);
            //tx.setText(REcognise);
        }
    });
    record.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try {

        System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");

                duplex.recognize(mic.getTargetDataLine(), mic.getAudioFormat());
                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);
                //response.setText(REcognise);
                JLabel label = new JLabel(REcognise);
                label.add(label);

                frame.add(recordBar);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The other code is important, the one you're using for speech recognition. If I'm not mistaking that works by sending `byte` arrays of audio data to a server, if that is the case, you can save those bytes to a file as well as sending them.

Comment: i have added the other  code also please do check and provide the needed idea